How to make the user not be able to put in a input while my text is slow printing in replit?
Having trouble with user interrupt in my output code
when the user puts in an input before the text is done slow printing it registered as a input and doesn't give the user time to think if they made this mistake i was expecting for it to wait for the text to stop printing then get the user input

You can flush the standard input so that whatever the user inputs during the slow output is discarded.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
